# Apigee EdgeMicro configuration issue

Tags: api-gateway, apigee

I am getting the below error while trying to configure Apigee EdgeMicro using the below command on our Apigee private cloud instance, knowing that I set the required args correctly, can somebody help us please? Thanks!

edgemicro private configure -o dtoe -e dev -u *** -p *** -r https://sandbox.api.stc.com.sa:9555 -m https://10.21.180.112:3001 -v internal

2024-02-29T12:11:40.179Z [15966] [microgateway edgemicro] current nodejs version is v20.11.1

2024-02-29T12:11:40.182Z [15966] [microgateway edgemicro] current edgemicro version is 3.3.2

2024-02-29T12:11:41.678Z [15974] [microgateway private] delete cache config

2024-02-29T12:11:41.680Z [15974] [microgateway private] deleted /home/kgalal/.edgemicro/dtoe-dev-config.yaml

2024-02-29T12:11:41.684Z [15974] [microgateway private] init config

2024-02-29T12:11:41.685Z [15974] [microgateway-config io] file doesn't exist, setting up

2024-02-29T12:11:41.725Z [15974] [microgateway private] Proxy edgemicro-internal is already deployed

2024-02-29T12:11:41.725Z [15974] [microgateway private] edgemicro-auth is already deployed

2024-02-29T12:11:41.725Z [15974] [microgateway private] checking org for existing KVM

2024-02-29T12:11:41.728Z [15974] [microgateway private] KVM already exists in your org

2024-02-29T12:11:41.762Z [15974] [microgateway private] Error: cannot GET https://sandbox.api.stc.com.sa:9555/edgemicro-auth/publicKey (404)

at translateError (/home/kgalal/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.1/lib/node_modules/edgemicro/cli/lib/cert-lib.js:365:15)

at Request._callback (/home/kgalal/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.1/lib/node_modules/edgemicro/cli/lib/cert-lib.js:400:15)

at Request.self.callback (/home/kgalal/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.1/lib/node_modules/edgemicro/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)

at Request.emit (node:events:518:28)

at Request. (/home/kgalal/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.1/lib/node_modules/edgemicro/node_modules/request/request.js:1154:10)

at Request.emit (node:events:518:28)

at IncomingMessage. (/home/kgalal/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.1/lib/node_modules/edgemicro/node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12)

at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:632:28)

at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:530:35)

at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12) {

text: '{"fault":{"faultstring":"Unable to identify proxy for host: internal and url: \/edgemicro-auth\/publicKey","detail":{"errorcode":"messaging.adaptors.http.flow.ApplicationNotFound"}}}'

}

I am trying to generate the yaml files of Apigee edge micro to install it on k8s cluster, but I am getting the above error.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.